# Reflection - invoke

Tags: java, reflection

having the class:

```
public class TestClass {
    public void testMethod() {
    }
```

I want to pass it to the below executor method, that should invoke its testMethod method.

```
public class SimpleUnitTester {
    public int executor(Class clazz) {
        Object clazzObject = clazz.newInstance();
        for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            m.invoke(clazzObject)); <--
        }
    }
}
```

But its obviously wrong. What is the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but you probably call it wrong. Add the implementation to the `testMethod` to see if it has been executed.

```
public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hi, I have been executed ^^");
}
```

Change the return type of the `executor(Class clazz)` method to `void` and call it as it is:

```
executor(TestClass.class);
```